# Duplicate timestamps values in grafana and thanos datasource showing single timestamp value

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, grafana, telegraf, thanos

Grafana showing duplicate timestamps values and Thanos showing the correct single timestamp value. I'm hitting a single curl request for application API Thanos showing the correct value but when I'm running the same query in grafana it shows two count values. I'm using telegraf agent for collecting metrics in prometheus.

My whole setup is running in Kubernetes and I'm using telegraf statsd for application monitoring.

[image: Thanos dashboard]

[image: Grafana dashboard]

Telegraf conf >>

```
[agent]
  interval = "15s"
  round_interval = true


  metric_batch_size = 1000

  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  flush_buffer_when_full = true

  collection_jitter = "0s"

  flush_interval = "1s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  quiet = false


  debug = false

   logfile = "/var/log/telegraf/telegraf.log"

   logfile_rotation_max_size = "10MB"

   logfile_rotation_max_archives = 5

   hostname = "${HOSTNAME}"


   [global_tags]
    dc = "${datacenter}"
    component = "k8s"
    role = "node"
    job  = "${job}"
    service = "containerorchestration"
    subcomponent = "worker"
    organization = "${organization}"
    environment = "${environment}"
    environmentversion = "${environmentversion}"
    infraversion = "${infraversion}"



  [[inputs.cpu]]
    percpu = false
    totalcpu = true
    fielddrop = ["time_*"]

  [[inputs.disk]]
    ignore_fs = ["tmpfs", "devtmpfs", "devfs", "overlay", "aufs", "squashfs"]

  [[inputs.diskio]]

  [[inputs.kernel]]

  [[inputs.mem]]

  [[inputs.processes]]

  [[inputs.swap]]

  [[inputs.system]]

  [[inputs.net]]
    fielddrop = ["icmp_*", "icmpmsg_*", "tcp_*", "udp_*", "udplite_*", "ip_*"]

  [[inputs.netstat]]

  [[inputs.linux_sysctl_fs]]




 [[outputs.prometheus_client]]
   listen = ":9273"
   metric_version = 2
   path = "/metrics"
   expiration_interval = "16s"
   export_timestamp = true
```

Telegraf statd conf >>

```
[[inputs.statsd]]
  protocol = "udp"
  max_tcp_connections = 250
  tcp_keep_alive = false

  service_address = ":8130"

  delete_gauges = true
  delete_counters = true
  delete_sets = true
  delete_timings = true
  parse_data_dog_tags = true

  percentiles = [90.0, 95.0, 99.0]

  metric_separator = "_"

  datadog_extensions = true

  allowed_pending_messages = 10000

  percentile_limit = 1000
```

And Prometheus job conf >

```
- job_name: 'ec2-telegraf'
  sample_limit: 4000
  metrics_path: '/metrics'
  scrape_interval: '15s'
  ec2_sd_configs:
    - region: "XXXXXXX"
      profile: "XXXXXXXXXX"
      role_arn: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      refresh_interval: 100s
      port: 9273
      filters:
        - name: instance-state-name
          values:
            - running
        - name: tag:Environment
          values:
            - performance
        
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_Businessunit]
      target_label: businessunit
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_Environment]
      target_label: environment
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_Techteam]
      target_label: techteam
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_component]
      target_label: component
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_subcomponent]
      target_label: subcomponent
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_role]
      target_label: role
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_aws_autoscaling_groupName]
      target_label: asgname
    - source_labels: [__meta_ec2_tag_Service]
      target_label: service
```

Need help, please share the suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: What's Grafana datasource? If using Thanos, should we guess that there's several Prometheus you're aggregating data from? If so, any chance your telegraf stuff pulls its metrics out of multiple prometheus? Have you tried getting them out of Thanos querier?

Comment: Yes using Thanos.
@SYN I tried with Prometheus as well, I have faced the same problem there. Sometimes getting the correct value and sometimes getting duplicate values.

Comment: in a Prometheus/Thanos setup, there should be some label, added by Prometheus, for Thanos to distinguish your Prometheus instances -- preventing duplicate metrics from being served. The Thanos Query worker should have some `--query.replica-label` option. Duplicates in Grafana sounds like something could be wrong with that option...

Comment: @SYN I have passed   "- --query.replica-label=prometheus_replica" to Thanos Query and added labels to Prometheus "prometheus_replica: $(POD_NAME)"

Comment: Sounds good then. And you're sure Grafana datasource points to that Thanos Query? There shouldn't be duplicates then. Also, if they were duplicates, your expression should sum them up, rather than display two consecutive bars, shouldn't it? Maybe try simplifying the expression, removing the sum by and sum_over_time, see which labels would come back with the metrics being summed up?

Comment: Oh... and, AFAIR, variables in prometheus config won't get evaluated. I would usually sed some placeholder in the prometheus configuration, fixing that replica name in an initContainer, before startup. If you query Prometheus directly, not going through Thanos Query, are you sure your Prometheus instances actually label their metrics with different replica label?